# Low number of requests/second on process that writes files on disk

Tags: java, performance, scala

I have a process that receives a lot of requests and i'm running some load tests using Apache Bench to find out why it's so slow (240 requests/second).

I've isolated all points and i found what the part that is slow:

```
def writeEmailToFile(mailMessage:MimeMessage, outputPath:String) ={
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mailMessage.writeTo(baos, Array[String]("X-Sender"))
    baos.close()
    /*
    //after i'll need to include it as first line
    val emailContent = new StringBuilder()
    emailContent.append("X-Sender: ")
    emailContent.append(mailMessage.getHeader("X-Sender")(0))
    emailContent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
    emailContent.append(new String(baos.toByteArray, "UTF-8"))
    */
    val fw = new FileWriter(outputPath)
    fw.write(new String(baos.toByteArray, "UTF-8"))
    fw.flush()
    fw.close()
}
```

This is the code after i did some optimizations but still slow - before the optimization it was 98 requests/second and now i have 240 requests/second.

Anybody could help me how to improve this method? I'm creating a ByteArrayOutoutStream and adding X-Send again because this must the first line on file.

Thank in advance.

Writing bytes: 322 requests/second.

```
def writeEmailToFile(mailMessage:MimeMessage, outputPath:String) ={
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)
    mailMessage.writeTo(baos, Array[String]("X-Sender"))
    baos.writeTo(outputStream)
    outputStream.flush()
    outputStream.close()
    baos.flush()
    baos.close()
}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, why are you converting the byte array to a string? Why not just write the binary data straight to disk? (That will be taking *some* of your CPU... quite possibly a fair amount.)

Comment: I'm doing that because i need to write that code that is commented. X-Sender must be in first line. Do you know how can write the binary data after X-Sender content (something like fw.write("blabla"); fw.write(binary)?)?

Comment: Well I'd out `OutputStreamWriter` anyway, write out the text, flush the write, then write the binary data straight to the underlying stream.

Comment: Let me try it right now :)

Comment: @JonSkeet check edit, please. That's what you were talking about? I have a problem using only bytes. I need to add a "." if the line starts with a ".". Is best to use binary data and read the file again instead convert to String?

Comment: No, that's not quite what I meant - but do you need the rest of the data in memory at all? If not, you don't need a ByteArrayOutputStream...

Comment: I don't need anything on memory. Could you show an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what `mailMessage.writeTo(baos, Array[String]("X-Sender"))` actually does, but it feels like your initial code is being very wasteful in converting everything to a string and back, and even your second code is doing a lot of stuff in memory that can go straight to disk:

```
// TODO: Try wrapping this in a BufferedOutputStream
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputPath)) {
    mailMessage.writeTo(output, Array[String]("X-Sender"));
}
```

Basically, the more intervening steps you remove, the less work will be required. If `mailMessage.writeTo` writes to the stream it's given in lots of small chunks, using a `BufferedOutputStream` may help - you should test that for yourself.

Comment: I've tried both ways and still stuck on 310-322 requests/second. Maybe this is the limit and i should think to implement a Load Balance. Your solution is very elegant but it will not work for me because i need to manipulate data before write to file and i'll have another gap when i go for it. If i use a StringBuilder to create the data instead MimeMessage, my throughput is lower: 262 requests/second. Another point is to connect direct to SMTP instead write files.

Comment: @placplacboom: That's why I asked you if you needed it in memory - you said you didn't. You clearly *do* if you need to manipulate it before you write it to the file. It's hard to help you if the requirements change. I would try to scale horizontally rather than vertically at this point though.

Comment: My fault, sorry. I'll talk to infrastructure to scale. We have optimized all code and database calls but when we start write file on disk, it is a disaster - so slow. And we are using VM, i have asked to increase memory and processor, but without lucky. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Scale "horizontally" also includes parallel processing of requests. How many simultaneous threads do you use?